# Inspecting local html files using WAVE tool

Tags: accessibility, wave

Wave web accessibility tool could be used to inspect webpages to check their compliance with accessibility standards for visually challenged. Is there any way this online tool or its Chrome extension, could be used to inspect html files hosted in local desktop server?

Comment: Do you mean behind a local http (http://) server, or do you mean files situated on the file system (file://)?

Comment: @unobf, I meant both.

Comment: You can definitely use aXe to do this analysis for both types of files https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/axe-devtools and https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/axe/lhdoppojpmngadmnindnejefpokejbdd?hl=en-US

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an old question, but for the benefit anyone else finding it as I did in a search for the Chrome WAVE extension not working for localhost URLs...

It appears that you need to enable "Allow access to file URLs".

Right click the WAVE icon, click "Manage Extensions" and flip the "Allow access to file URLs" switch.

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox aXe extension https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/axe-devtools and the Chrome aXe extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/axe/lhdoppojpmngadmnindnejefpokejbdd?hl=en-US both allow for analyzing files that are on a server, on a local server and on the local file system.

The aXe rules are newer than the WAVE rules and the instructions that are provided when you click the "more info" link are clear and precise. If you are using WAVE, you should definitely give aXe a test drive.

Comment: Thanks @unobf. That would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can open the page in a browser, you can use the extension to check the page. I just tried it with both a page running on localhost and a page I opened as just a file on C drive.

I'm using the WAVE add-on in Firefox.

According to [their site](http://wave.webaim.org/extension/):

> The toolbar can check intranet, password-protected, dynamically generated, or sensitive web pages. Also, because the WAVE toolbar evaluates the rendered version of your page, locally displayed styles and dynamically-generated content from scripts or AJAX can be evaluated.

The online tool, however, requires a public URL.

Comment: Thank You! It works fine in Firefox. It doesn't seem to work in Google Chrome, that's why I had to post this question.